# Custom Twitter Implementation

Tags: jquery, html, twitter, custom-controls

I'm trying to implement the latest tweet from my company's twitter account on my company's website. Not multiple ones, just the most recent.
I found a website that is doing exactly what I want, but I can't figure out how they're doing it. I legit have read and searched every script they're running but there seems to be no connection that asks for the twitter handle.  No php, no json no anything.

Is there a jquery plugin I am not aware of?

The site is http://willowtreeapps.com/

The twitter feed sits right above the footer on the home page. Can someone take a look and maybe help me with this? My bosses are very set on having something similar and I can't let them down.
Thanks so much

Comment: That seems to be a wordpress widget, so there is probably server-side code getting the tweet. you wouldn't be able to see the server side code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be ways to do this with API v1.0 to pull the JSON from Twitter but then they changed the way the API worked and you needed to authenticate with oAuth.

https://github.com/andrewbiggart/latest-tweets-php-o-auth

You will generally not see PHP as it is executed on the server and outputted as HTML.  It is possible they are using the new API v1.1 with PHP and then just the content to a div.

The old jQuery way will not work as the API is gone.
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/display-last-tweet/

You can however use a custom timeline widget with Twitter.  It isn't easy but you can then use jQuery to fiddle with the iframe and remove contents and classes.  Not really worth it.

Search google for latest Tweet and you will find some plugins that will work or you can implement the github new API I posted.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in twitter that lets you embed a twitter timeline in your web page. Go to settings -> Widgets and there you can find the twitter timeline. You have to make the twitter account public for the tweets to be seen by everyone. The problem with the timeline is that is has default styles (twitter styles). It is possible to modify them but is a little bit tedious.

Here you have the instructions to embed a twitter timeline into your website

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines

The other option you have is to use Twitter REST API, here you have the documentation

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

You can do GET and POST requests to the Twitter REST API and get the information you want. There you can get the JSON of the information you are interested in (in this case the tweets of that account) and show them with your own styles in your website.

Comment: Beat me by 14 seconds.  Yes, modifying the css on the embeded timelines works but when a new tweet comes in your lose your style.  Plus, you need to delay the page loading to make sure it is fully loaded in the iframe first.

Comment: Yes, thats why the Twitter REST API is the best option to show your tweets. With that, you don't break you website styles

Comment: Thanks so much for the comments. Do you guys have instructions on how to use the REST API? That's a little foreign to me. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

thanks so much for participating. It seems that with the new API twitter has limited the customization one can accomplish :(
http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/custom-twitter-feed-integration-jquery/ this guys has a sort-of way but I can't seem to get that working either. Maybe it helps someone else.
Thanks again